# <h:inputText> in <ui:repeat> submits only the last row

Tags: jsf, arraylist, user-input, uirepeat

I am trying to change `ArrayList` in xhtml page using managed bean. 
When I am entering data to the table, only the last row in the table getting the data in to the `ArrayList`. Here is the code.

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" 
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css"/>
    <h:head>
        <title>Web TIme :  A simple example Title</title>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60"/>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <div class="w3-container w3-light-grey w3-border">
        <p>Today : #{webTimeBean.time}</p>
        <p>Hello : #{userBean.email}</p>
        </div>    
            <table class="w3-table w3-bordered w3-striped">
       <tr>
            <th>Game #</th>
            <th>Home Team</th>
            <th>Away Team</th>
            <th>Home Score </th>
            <th>Away Score</th>
            <th>Bet</th>
      </tr>
                <ui:repeat var="elem" value="#{userBean.matchList}"  >
        <tr>
            <h:form>
             <td>
                 <h:outputText value="#{elem.matchNumber}"  />
            </td>
            <td>
                <h:outputText value="#{elem.homeTeam}" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <h:outputText value="#{elem.awayTeam}" />
            </td>

            <td>
                <h:inputText id="homeS" value="#{elem.homeScore}" size="2">
                   <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="1" type="number" integerOnly="true" />             
                 </h:inputText>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h:inputText id="awayS" value="#{elem.awayScore}" size="2" />
            </td>
             <td>
                 <h:commandButton  value=" Bet " class="w3-btn-block w3-teal" action="#{userBean.setGameBet(elem.matchNumber , elem.homeScore , elem.awayScore)}"   />     
            </td>
            </h:form>
       </tr>
            </ui:repeat>
        </table> 
    </h:body>
</html>
```

now to the Java Code  :

```
@ManagedBean( name="userBean" )
@SessionScoped

public class UserBean implements Serializable {  

private static List<User> tblScore ; 
private String firstName= "First Name "; 
private String lastName = "Last Name ";
private String email = "Email";
private String userName = "User Name";
private int totalPoints ;
private String password = "Password"; 
private  static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger();
private static PrelogInQueries login ; 
//private List<Game> temp ; 
private List<matchBean> matchList ; 
public UserBean() 
{
    matchList = new ArrayList();
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}


public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public int getTotalPoints() {
    return totalPoints;
}

public void setTotalPoints(int totalPoints) {
    this.totalPoints = totalPoints;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public List<User> getTblScore() {
    return tblScore;
}

public void setTblScore(List<User> tblScore) {
    this.tblScore = tblScore;
}

public static PrelogInQueries getLogin() {
    return login;
}

public static void setLogin(PrelogInQueries login) {
    UserBean.login = login;
}

public List<matchBean> getMatchList() {
    return matchList;
}

public void setMatchList(List<matchBean> matchList) {
    this.matchList = matchList;
}




public String verifyLogin()
{
    logger.log(Logger.LEVEL.INFO, "Insert to verifyLogin with email :" + email );
    login = new PrelogInQueries();
    boolean verified = false ; 
    verified = login.verifyMail(email , password ) ; 
    //userName = login.getUserName(email);
    //tblScore = new ArrayList(); 
    try { 
        tblScore =  login.loadTableScore();
        //temp = login.getRoundInfo();
        for ( int i = 0 ; i<tblScore.size() ; i++ )
        {
            logger.log(Logger.LEVEL.INFO, "tblScore :" + tblScore.get(i).getUserName() + "  " + tblScore.get(i).getTotalPoints() );
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UserBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    if ( verified ==false  ) 
     return "/index.xhtml";
    else 
    {

    return "/welcome.xhtml"; 
    }
}

   public String nextRound()
{
    try { 
        matchList = login.getRoundInfo2();
        printArray ();
        logger.log(logging.Logger.LEVEL.INFO, "nextRound ");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
       logger.log(Logger.LEVEL.INFO, " catch EXCEPTION ERROR : nextRound() " ) ;
    }
    return "/nextround.xhtml";
}

public void printArray () 
{
    logger.log(logging.Logger.LEVEL.INFO, "printArray "); 
    for (int i = 0 ; i <matchList.size() ; i ++ )
    {
      logger.log(logging.Logger.LEVEL.INFO, "USER_BEAN =  Game # " +matchList.get(i).getMatchNumber() + " @ "+ matchList.get(i).getHomeTeam() + " vs " + matchList.get(i).getAwayTeam() +"  "+ matchList.get(i).getHomeScore() +"  "+ matchList.get(i).getAwayScore() ) ;   
    }
} 

public void setGameBet( int gamenumber , int hScore , int aScore   )
{
    logger.log(logging.Logger.LEVEL.INFO, "*** setGameBet ***    "   + gamenumber + " = " + hScore + " - " + aScore );
    printArray();
    boolean t = setBet ( gamenumber , hScore ,aScore); 
    logger.log(logging.Logger.LEVEL.INFO, "*** Is setGameBet Done secsessfully ?: "   + t );
    printArray();
}

 public boolean setBet( int gamenumber ,  int home , int away)
{
    int indexToUpDate = getGameIndex (gamenumber) ; 
    if ( indexToUpDate == -1 )
    {
        return false ; 
    }
    else 
    {
       logger.log(logging.Logger.LEVEL.INFO, "*** Match Number Found !!  ***   match number: "   + gamenumber + " = " + home + " - " + away );
        matchBean toUpdate = matchList.get(indexToUpDate);
        toUpdate.setHomeScore(home);
        toUpdate.setAwayScore(away);
        matchList.set(indexToUpDate, toUpdate) ; 
        return true ; 
    }
}

public int getGameIndex (int matchNum ) 
{   
     for ( int i = 0 ; i <matchList.size() ; i ++ )
     {

         if ( matchList.get(i).getMatchNumber() == matchNum )
         {     
             logger.log(logging.Logger.LEVEL.INFO, "*** getGameIndex ***    i="+ i );
             return i ; 
         }      
     }
     return -1 ; 
}
```

}

note : in the log i can see that i am getting the match number once clicking on the "bet" button but the scores stay 0 unless i am clicking on the last button at the last row .

Comment: Coud you post your Java code?

Comment: sure ... adding the java code